# Can I remove app/assets on heroku after asset compilation to reduce slug size

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sprockets, asset-sync

Just a ponder.  If you compile assets with asset_sync gem and do not fallback to have sprockets compile on runtime can you remove the app/assets folder from your slug using .slugignore to reduce slug size?

I've tested and the precompiled assets are not longer served using asset pipeline.  Rails must look for the app/assets folder and gets grumpy if it's not available, defaulting to on-demand compilation.

Anyone else tried anything to this effect?  The only thing I've found is that build backs are called after slug-ignore so if I'm using the turbo sprockets it might muck up the caching  between deploys.

Comment: I haven't tried to do this, but I believe that precompiled assets on Heroku are stored in `/public/assets`, which is in the asset pipeline...  This is an interesting idea, though.

Comment: Good point CDub. That means that there are two sources of assets that are essentially dead weight. If we are serving all assets from an asset host then the app/assets folder and public/assets folder are never accessed.

Comment: Bingo.  Having slept on this, I'm thinking maybe if you do `rake assets:precompile` *before* you deploy, you could ignore all asset pipeline on deploy to Heroku…  Thoughts?

Comment: I was on the same page but I realized it might be easier to just destroy all assets with a post compile hook.

Comment: I'm not sure that's possible to do with Heroku hooks.  If you can, I'd love to know how.

Answer (score 3):

[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13149758/put-assets-in-slugignore-for-heroku-deployments-with-asset-sync-s3-cdn) has a great solution for this with a post precompile task.  I modified it to remove everything, including the app/assets files. It might be a bit drastic for some folks but it's a simple way to cut some cruft.

This reduced my slug size by 20mb.

```
Rake::Task["assets:precompile"].enhance do
  return "can't run in dev" if Rails.env.development?
  puts 'my assets:precompile hook is started!'
  ["#{Dir.pwd}/public/", "#{Dir.pwd}/app/assets/"].each do |dir_path|
    records = Dir.glob("#{dir_path}**/*")
    records.each do |f|
      if f =~ /.*.png$/ or
        f =~ /.*.jpg$/ or
        f =~ /.*.gif$/ or
        f =~ /.*.ico$/ or
        f =~ /.*.eot$/ or
        f =~ /.*.svg$/ or
        f =~ /.*.woff$/ or
        f =~ /.*.ttf$/ or
        f =~ /.*.otf$/ or
        f =~ /.*.css$/ or
        f =~ /.*.js$/ or
        f =~ /.*.sass$/ or
        f =~ /.*.css$/ or
        f =~ /.*.scss$/ or
        f =~ /.*.coffee$/ or
        f =~ /.*.wav$/ then
        File.delete(f)
        puts "removing #{f}"
      end
    end
    puts Dir.glob("#{dir_path}**/*")
  end
  puts 'my assets:precompile hook is finished!'
end
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of reasons that the slug size is too large. 3 of the most common are:

- Extra/Unused Gems
- Tmp Cacheing
- Large assets through .slugignore

I spent about 3 hours going through all of the possibilities of why my slug size was too large.

All of the gems I have in my gem file I need, so that's out.
I tried using a .slugignore via https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler and that helped a little bit.

The final solution for me was **ignoring assets from other environments.**

To do this, open application.rb and add:

`config.assets.configure do |env|
      if Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.test?
 env.cache = ActiveSupport::Cache.lookup_store(:memory_store)`

This will ignore any extra cacheing that is getting pulled in from other environments.
If you are deploying to heroku, before you precompile, run: 
`heroku config:set BUNDLE_WITHOUT="development:test"`. After, run your regular `git push heroku master`.

If you look back in the log, you will notice that it skipped right over development and test. This reduced my slug size by over 50mb. I hope this helps somebody!